# SIF error while installing Sitecore 10.2 using Sitecore Install Assistant's user interface

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I am installing `Sitecore 10.2` using `Sitecore Install Assistant's user interface` and facing the below issue while installation.
[image]

> The repository could not be registered because there exists a registered repository with Name 'SitecoreGallery' and SourceLocation 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2'. To register another repository with Name 'Temp8abc6d53-84f8-4c41-94ae-a57636a9f92a', please unregister the existing repository using the Unregister-PSRepository cmdlet.
> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Repository'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
> The specified module 'SitecoreInstallFramework' with version '2.3.0' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error states that the repository is already registered with name and source location and you need to install the specified module with mentioned version.

If you already have a repository then run the below command and update it:

```
Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
```

After this run the below command to verify that the repository was installed successfully or not:

```
Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework –ListAvailable
```

Output will be:
[image]

Now re-run the setup again:
[image]